# a verb or a phrase to describe the start of existing

Tags: word-request

What word or phrase would fit in best here?

> She says that trepanation began to be practiced only in Europe during the Dark Ages
> because Pope once issued an edict saying that that kind of practice
> would help Christians get rid of their curse, but does she know that
> that medical practice existed in ancient China and in ancient Maya long before any
> Pope ____________ ?

1. emerged
2. came about
3. existed
4. appeared
5. began to be
6. ?

Comment: I would use existed, even though it does not explicitly refer to the beginning of the Papacy. BTW in the second line it should be *the* Pope.

Comment: Existed, definitely. For accentuating the cause, you can say, 'ever existed'.

Comment: I think this is entirely a matter of stylistic choices, which makes it Off Topic POB. For what it's worth, ***this*** writer wouldn't bother with any verb at all after ***long before any Pope***, just as I wouldn't necessarily add an extra verb at the end of ***Dinosaurs existed long before people***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - Why! How come I didn't think of that option! It looks like my problem is solved even easier that what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - What is POB?

Comment: sorry - that's *Primarily Opinion-Based,* which used to be one of the closevote reasons here (or maybe over on ELU - it was probably a long time ago now).

Comment: ...Stylistically speaking I'd consider making the additional change to *...long before **[even] the first** Pope*, but you have lots of alternatives to choose from here. The text does have various "weaknesses" though - not least of which is that the word ***only*** is almost certainly in the "wrong" position (and that one affects the *meaning*, so it's not just a stylistic choice).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - I see. Thank you. Can you, please, tell me where the word "only" should be? Her thought was that trepanation was being practiced at that time nowhere else except for Europe.

Comment: Oh. Well it strikes me as very "odd" to say that trepanning began to be practised in Europe, ***but nowhere else*** because of a papal edict. But if that's what was intended, I can hardly argue. It's just that idiomatically, we would normally expect ***only*** to come before the main verb ***began** [to be practised]* OR before the conjunction ***because*** in such a context. Where the word ***only*** implies that ***if that papal edict had not been issued***, there wouldn't have been any trepanning in Europe in the Dark Ages. So it looks a bit confusing.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - I see. Thank you. Do you think putting "only in Europe" in parentheses would avoid this confusion? Like this:  "She says that trepanation began to be practiced (only in Europe) during the Dark Ages because Pope once issued an edict..."

Comment: Excellent suggestion! In fact, I was going to suggest that myself, but I decided not to on the grounds that you've already got quite a long and complex sentence there, so maybe more drastic rephrasing might be better. But there's no doubt that putting the ***only*** clause in brackets completely resolves the problem of anyone misparsing the text the way I did. I don't want to get bogged down in comparing possible alternative ways of putting it, but at least your comment shows that you understand how ***only*** works in this exact context.

Comment: (***but*** I still think that *logically*, the "concessive" clause ***but does she know that...*** doesn't really have much to draw a contrast against unless ***only*** refers to the ***fact*** of that papal edict being issued, rather than its geographical reach! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica - I see. Thank you very much for all the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll comment on each, as they're different in sentiment:

> emerged

This implies that a Pope existed, but was somehow hidden or covered. That isn't what you want.

> came about

If something "comes about" it's normally a *circumstance*. For example: "A crisis came about in 1889..."

> existed

This would work, and is probably closest. But it's very direct, and perhaps not what you're *trying to say* with your sentence.

> appeared

Similar to "emerged" it feels like the Pope existed in hiding, or wasn't well known.

> began to be

This is odd, it sounds like a Pope's birth.

Some more suggestions:

> long before any Pope **was chosen**

Redirect the focus to the act of actually selecting a Pope, rather than the person existing.

> long before **the [role of Pope/papacy] was created**.

Perhaps consider talking about the role or position instead.